# Type inference using an IList<T> and params T[]

Tags: c#

Here's another question on the compilers choice when it comes to type inference.

In this code snippet, you can see that the `DoStuff` method accepting `params[]` is creating a `List<T>` which implements `IList<T>`. The output however is a recursive call to the `DoStuff` method accepting `params` which eventually results in a stack overflow.

I know the obvious solution here is to simply declare `set` as `IList<T>` but I'd like to know why the compiler chose the `DoStuff` method accepting `params[]`.

```
void Main()
{
    new TypeInferenceTest();
}

class TypeInferenceTest {

    public TypeInferenceTest() {
        DoStuff("a", "b");
    }

    // Why are you not executed?
    public static void DoStuff<T>(IList<T> set) {

        Console.WriteLine ("DoStuff IList<T>");

        foreach (var element in set)
        {
            Console.WriteLine (element);
        }
    }

    public static void DoStuff<T>(params T[] items) {

        Console.WriteLine("DoStuff params[]");

        List<T> set = new List<T>();
        foreach (T t in items) {
            if (t == null)
                continue;
            set.Add(t);
        }
        DoStuff(set);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
DoStuff params[]
DoStuff params[]
DoStuff params[]
DoStuff params[]
...
```

Comment: My advice: **do not design method overloads like this**. It causes nothing but pain and confusion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can make a much simpler reproducer of your problem.

```
class Animal {}
class Tiger : Animal {}
...
static void M(Animal animal) {}
static void M<T>(params T[] items) {}
...
M(new Tiger());
```

which is chosen?

We have two choices, `M(Animal)` and the expanded form of the params method: `M<Tiger>(Tiger)`. The former requires converting a tiger to an animal; the latter is an exact match for the argument type. Therefore the latter is chosen.

Now suppose we have

```
Animal animal = new Tiger();
M(animal);
```

Now what happens?

We have two choices. `M(Animal)` and the expanded form of the params method: `M<Animal>(Animal)`.  The formal parameter types are identical and both are exact matches. The compiler falls back to a tiebreaking round: if one of them was "natural" and one of them was only `Animal` due to generic substitution, then the natural one wins. So in this case the former would win.

Comment: I was expection eric to break our assumptions and to say the fact. Appeared! Thanks eric. Good answer as always :)

Answer (score 2):

Compiler always chooses the method which is more closer, [Closer is better](http://ericlippert.com/2013/12/23/closer-is-better/).

`DoStuff<T>` is generic which means it can suit for any type and it is the closer one when there is no overload for specific type (`List<T>` in this case) hence compiler chooses `DoStuff<T>(params T[] items)` than `DoStuff<T>(IList<T> set)`.

I believe compiler will assume closer when there is no implicit conversion required, in this case to convert `List<T>` to `IList<T>` compiler requires implicit conversion, but `DoStuff<T>(params T[] items)` is already generic can take any type with no conversion required so compiler is happy to choose this overload.

You can fix this by either declaring `void DoStuff<T>(List<T> set)` or by declaring variable as `IList<T> set`.

P.S: I may be wrong, this is my assumption about compiler, may Eric Lippert appear and clear the confusion :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer I appreciate the time you spent. However, I'd rather not rely on assumptions.

Comment: This answer is almost correct; the first statement has nothing to do with this problem because both methods are equally close. But the conclusion is correct: there is an argument of type `List<T>` and the compiler must choose between `DoStuff<T>(IList<T>)` and the expanded form `DoStuff<List<T>>(List<T>)`. Since the latter is an exact match and the former is not, the latter is chosen.

Answer (score -3):

It is because the "a", "b" arguments are automatically created as a 2 element array of strings since they are convertible into params T[] items, therefore the 2nd DoStuff signature is matched.

See: Parameter arrays on MSDN for more info.

Comment: That is not the question.The question is why `DoStuff(set);` mathces with `params` instead of `DoStuff<T>(IList<T> set)` while `set` is a `List<T>`